# VB.NET Visual Studio 2010 Don't get IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here is the code in VB.NET (using Visual Studio 2010)... in the form_load event.

```
Dim tNumberInteger(3) As Integer
tNumberInteger(0) = 10
tNumberInteger(1) = 10
tNumberInteger(2) = 10
tNumberInteger(3) = 10
tNumberInteger(4) = 10 ' Suppose to get System.IndexOutOfRangeException here !!!
```

If I double click on My Project, I have the following settings:

```
Option Explicit : On
Option Strict: On
Option Compare: On
Option Infer On
```

Why I don't get the IndexoutOfRangeException on the tNumberInteger(4) = 10 ?
Some students have the same problem, on others it's working fine. I don't see any differences in the settings.

Comment: Is that your exact code?  Are you sure your iNumberInteger is not being redefined or resized elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a 64-bit WinForms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-64-bit-winforms-application)

Answer (score 2):

I also had some problem when dealing with exceptions in the form load event of the main form.

See [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357311/silent-exceptions-on-x64-development-machines) from Microsoft for more details.

You can also try your code outside the Form.Load event to see if it fixes your problem.